# Looping SoundEffectInstance crackles when paused?

Tags: xna, slimdx, monogame

Using Monogame 3.0.1 on Win8, I have a SoundEffectInstance that loops seamlessly if I let it continue to play. However, when I play and stop it (or pause and resume) repeatedly, it often results in a loud pop or crack when it transitions from playing to silent (or vice versa). Is this an issue with the sound file, the library, or something else? Is there a better way to pause/resume a sound without the nasty side effect?

Answer (score 1):

I would say to try a handfull of random soundeffects and see if they produce the same results as yout current sound effect and post your findings as an update to your question. It would also be very helpful if you posted your sound effect code. Please follow these steps and I will be able to help more!